# conda-build and dependency resolution

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

I have a conda based project, which has a few dependencies declared in `meta.yaml`. These dependencies of course have their own dependencies, which aren't listed in my `meta.yaml`. As a result, building my project with `conda build` sometimes results in different dependencies being used for a build.

I would like to specify all the dependencies in some kind of a lock file, so that every time I do `conda build` the same dependencies are used.

I've looked at conda-build docs, and found [this section about reproducibility](https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/variants.html#about-reproducibility), but it doesn't really say how to create reproducible builds.

Is there any way to get `conda build` to use the same dependency tree every time it runs?

Answer (score 0):

I think this command should do the trick:

```
conda env export -n <your-env-name> > env.yml
```

The yml will not only include a list of all the packages in your environment, but also their version numbers and a unique hash as an identifier to ensure reproducability.